# yii2 Запрос с NOT EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Каким образом сделать запрос такого типа средствами Active Record ? Выбрать всех пользователей из таблицы user, которых нет в таблице branch_users

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM `branch_users`
                  WHERE branch_users.`user_id` = user.`id` 
                  )
```

В документации ничего не нашел на тему exists/not exists
Так не получилось

```
$vars = ArrayHelper::map(\common\models\User::find()
                ->from('user')
                ->where(['not exists', \common\models\BranchUsers::find()
                    ->select('*')
                    ->where(['branch_users.user_id' => 'user.id'])])
                ->all(), 'id', 'fullname');
```

Подскажите как правильно построить такой запрос??

Comment: А чё б не воспользоваться DAO?

Comment: `$subQuery = \common\models\BranchUsers::find()->select('user_id');
$query = \common\models\User::find()->where(['not exists', 'id', $subQuery]);
$models = $query->all();`  так поможет?

Comment: Ошибка `Subquery for EXISTS operator must be a Query object.`

Comment: Использовал 'not in' - все ок `$query = \common\models\User::find()->where(['not in', 'id', $subQuery]);`

Comment: попробовал ответ написать. Что-то я сомневаюсь, что `not in` это тоже самое что `not exists`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$subQuery = BranchUsers::find()->select('user_id')->from('branch_users b')->where('t.id = b.user_id'); 
$query = User::find()->from('user t')->where(['not exists', $subQuery]); 
// запрос
print_r($query->createCommand()->getRawSql());

$models = $query->all();
```

хотя в данном случае `BranchUsers::find()` и `User::find()` несколько бессмысленно, поэтому другой вариант, но по такому же принципу

```
$subQuery = (new \yii\db\Query)
        ->select('user_id')
        ->from('branch_users b')
        ->where('t.id = b.user_id');
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
                ->select('*')
                ->from('user t')
                ->where(['not exists', $subQuery]);
$command = $query->createCommand();

// запрос
print_r($query->createCommand()->getRawSql());
```

---

А вообще, я лично не вижу ничего постыдного или плохого в том, чтоб написать запрос напрямую через `DAO` (тем более не надо подставлять значений пользователя в запрос):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * 
FROM `user`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM `branch_users`
                  WHERE branch_users.`user_id` = user.`id` 
                  )';
Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

Мне искренне непонятно почему нужно обязательно рваться всё сделать через `AR` и прочее. Модно молодёжно стильно?